# Hystrix and Turbine does not work with Spring boot 2 and Spring cloud Finchley.M8

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, hystrix, turbine

I tried turbine + hystrix  dashboard with Spring boot 2 and latest versions of Spring cloud, seems exist some problem and turbine could not get stream from reactive service. I just uploaded simple microservices to github

https://github.com/armdev/reactive-spring-cloud

Exception like this:

```
com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor$MisconfiguredHostException: [{"timestamp":"2018-03-08T17:22:05.809+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/hystrix.stream"}]
    at com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor.init(InstanceMonitor.java:318) ~[turbine-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor.access$100(InstanceMonitor.java:103) ~[turbine-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor$2.call(InstanceMonitor.java:235) [turbine-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor$2.call(InstanceMonitor.java:229) [turbine-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

Or broken PIPE.

Any one tried full spring cloud stack with Spring webflux? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately problem solved by configuration, no any bug in Spring boot and Spring cloud. Many thanks to Josh Long ! 
Here you can find full project with config.
https://github.com/armdev/reactive-spring-cloud/blob/master/google/src/main/resources/application.properties

```
server.port=8082
spring.application.name=turbine
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=5
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=5
turbine.aggregator.cluster-config=default
turbine.app-config=google
turbine.cluster-name-expression= new String("default")
turbine.combine-host-port=true
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.default: actuator/hystrix.stream
```

Comment: Since you've been able to solve the problem, please accept your own answer and close this question.

Answer (score 1):

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
how to write it in yaml

Comment: in yml add like this   include: '*'